# How to remove lines containing less than 3 letters in Email Before "@"domain in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editors, text-editing, notepad

hello how do i remove lines containing less than 3 letters in email before 
@domain since @domains containing already more than 3 letters or 3 letters
i want to skip that and search before the @domain

so its s1111g@domain."anything":password lines

so the search will be before "@"domain like @gmail or @yahoo or any email

full example of file containing:

```
$test1@gmail.com:Keepline1
Ga@gmail.com:Removeline0
S*556&e@yahoo.com:Removeline0
*test2@hotmail.com:Keepline1
3%6%768()-S@yahoo.fr:Removeline0
¿H£1§¥889@gmail.com:Removeline0
Normal1@web.net:Keepline1
§Studio7746@club.ru:Keepline1
```

need result:

```
$test1@gmail.com:Keepline1
*test2@hotmail.com:Keepline1
Normal1@web.net:Keepline1
§Studio7746@club.ru:Keepline1
```

Comment: You have now asked 10 questions regarding regular expressions. Are you not learning anything from the answers you have been given so far?

Comment: nope i learned a lot and gived upvote to people who helped
but we are live until death learning from life ?

Comment: btw my questions it doesn't help me alone it help many around here
so what you try to blame me for ?

Comment: I'm not trying to blame you for anything. This question however is very similar to the last question you asked. Have you tried adapting the answer to the last question using what you have learned?

Comment: i tryied to edit the code to match this question but i fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:[^a-z@]*[a-z]){0,3}[^a-z@]*@.+(?:\R|$)`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
(?:         : start non capture group
  [^a-z@]*  : 0 or more non alphabetic or @
  [a-z]     : an alphabetic
){0,3}      : group exists from 0 up to 3 times
[^a-z@]*    : 0 or more non alphabetic or @
@           : literally @
.+          : 1 or more any character but newline
(?:\R|$)    : any kind of linebreak (\r, \n, \r\n) or end of line
```

*DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

**Result for given example:**

```
$test1@gmail.com:Keepline1
*test2@hotmail.com:Keepline1
Normal1@web.net:Keepline1
§Studio7746@club.ru:Keepline1
```

Comment: as always you a genius is there a way to contact you like skype or discord or fb ?